# Implement UIImagePickerController like contacts App with circular overlay

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to implement `UIImagePickerController` exactly like the Contacts App(iOS), but i am unable to bring the behavior in the same fashion like circular overlay on the Image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to mean `UIImageView`, not `UIImagePickerController`. If so, this is how you can do it:

```
image.layer.borderWidth=1.0
image.layer.masksToBounds = false
image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
image.layer.cornerRadius = 13
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.height/2
image.clipsToBounds = true
```

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for reply but i need for "UIImagePickerController" like cropping the image after taking the image

Comment: Then, what you need is manipulating the `UIImage` returned by the `UIImagePickerController`. Pretty simple. Let me answer again.

Answer (score 0):

For converting the UIImage returned by your UIImagePickerController, do this. Create a new class called UIImage+CircleMask. Make sure it's a UIImage subclass. You can customise with your UIImage, a corner radius of you preference or the standard `image.frame.size.height/2`. It will return a UIImage with your CircleMask

```
@interface UIImage (CircleMask)

+ (UIImage *)roundedRectImageFromImage :(UIImage *)image
                                  size :(CGSize)imageSize
                      withCornerRadius :(float)cornerRadius;

@end

@implementation UIImage(Overlay)

+(UIImage*)roundedRectImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image
                                size:(CGSize)imageSize
                    withCornerRadius:(float)cornerRadius
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0);   //  <= notice 0.0 as third scale parameter. It is important cause default draw scale ≠ 1.0. Try 1.0 - it will draw an ugly image..
    CGRect bounds=(CGRect){CGPointZero,imageSize};
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds
                                cornerRadius:cornerRadius] addClip];
    [image drawInRect:bounds];
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return finalImage;
}

@end
```

And on your `UIViewController`, don't forget to add this line:

```
  #import "UIImage+CircleMask.h"
```

Best regards,

Comment: can I zoom the image?, after zooming how can i get only the part of image which exists in the circle. I think u r code may returm full image in circle image. but i need only the part of image exists in the circle

Comment: shall i need to present another view controller when this method is called.

Comment: No, you don't need to present another `UIViewController`. For zooming the image, you'll need an `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`.